# How to call server-side function from client-side in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a web page having asp.net button control and textbox. I want a confirm message box, when someone changes the content of textbox and click on button. If user click on yes then event of button should fire other wise nothing should happen. All I want is to implement AJAX call back, but it is not working with ASP.NET button control.

Comment: please paste whatever you have done till now to help you better

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code to your aspx code

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" OnClientClick="return confirm('sure?');" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConfirmButtonExtender of the AjaxControlToolkit for this purpose,

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using `Client Callback` in ASP.Net, It is really nice feature in ASP.Net

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the use of [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) with javascript's [confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) as suggested by Pilgerstorfer Franz, with an update panel for the ajax request you mentioned...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server"/>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Should give you want you need.